# rare occurence of diffraction in light

Tags: optics

My question is that how the diffraction is not a common phenomenon of light.Here the lunar eclispe also is on the same basis but the diffraction is only a feature of sound .how?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Physics SE! Look around, and take the [tour].  As it stands, your question is unclear. Diffraction is a common phenomena with light, but there are many other interactions of light with matter. How does the lunar eclipse figure in to your question on the diffraction of light? Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

Noticeable diffraction occurs when the wavelength is similar in size to the obstacle in the path of the waves.  Sound waves are in the order of metres so we observe diffraction of sound fairly routinely.  Since the wavelength of light is so much smaller (and particularly tiny compared to the moon) we rarely see diffraction effects with light.

One place you do see diffraction effects with light is a diffraction grating for example with the separation of colours produced by a compact disc or the screen of a smartphone (turned off).

My personal favourite way to demonstrate refraction is to have someone hold their two thumbs parallel and very close together - less than 1 mm and then look between their thumbs at a light source (could be just daylight through a window).  If they look carefully they will see tiny light and dark bands parallel to the edges of their thumbs.